# List out all Facebook friends in native invite dialogbox in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying to invite facebook friends in ios. successfully i got the output also. I attached that output image also.
[image]

My Question is, here i can see the suggested friends list instead of display my all friends. but while am searching any of friends in search bar, then it display that search list. My code is,

```
 NSString *MY_URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"xxxxxxxxxx://host"];
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];
    [params setObject:@"Hi, Check out this app, You'll love it!" forKey:@"message"];
    [params setObject:MY_URL forKey:@"link"];

    [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:FBSession.activeSession
                                                  message:@"Friends Invite"
                                                    title:@"xxxxxxxx"
                                               parameters:params handler:
     ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"Url : %@",resultURL);
             NSLog(@"Result : %u",result);
             NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
             if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"]) {
                 // User clicked the Cancel button
                 NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
             } else {
                 // User clicked the Send button
                 NSString *requestID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                 NSLog(@"Request ID: %@", requestID);
             }
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Error : %@",[error localizedDescription]);
         }

     }];
```

My point is how can i display all my friends in this invite list itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Facebook Apps registered later than April 2014, you can not access to all friends unless you are implementing a game/canvas app. (if this is your case, you will need to use invitable_friends endpoint)

Otherwise, unfortunately, you will be able to only access users facebook friends who have already signedin to your app.

Note: Even if your app was created before April 2014, all friends will be useless after april 2015.

[For more info in facebook developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog?locale=en_GB)

`New features available in v2.0
Taggable Friends API: We've added a new endpoint called /me/taggable_friends that you can use in order to generate stories that have friends tagged in them, even those friends don't use your app. If you want to use the taggable friends API, your app will require review.
Invitable Friends API: We've added a new endpoint called /me/invitable_friends that you can use to generate a list of friends for someone to invite to your game through a custom interface. This API is only available to apps that are games on Facebook Canvas.`